# How to unzip, unpack and convert android rootfs to ext4

Tags: android, rootfs

Android rootfs is compressed and split into:

super.raw.00.gz, super.raw.01.gz, super.raw.03.gz, super.raw.04.gz

How to unzip, combine, unpack them to ext4 files that can be mounted ?

Answer (score 2):

Steps are:

Unzip each of the multi-zip files:

```
gzip -d super.raw.00.gz
gzip -d super.raw.01.gz
gzip -d super.raw.02.gz
gzip -d super.raw.03.gz
```

Concatenate them to a single file:

```
cat super.raw.00 super.raw.01 super.raw.02 super.raw.03 > super.raw
```

Unpack the super image using lpunpack tool. [Download link.](https://github.com/AndroidDumps/Firmware_extractor/blob/master/tools/Linux/bin/lpunpack)

```
./lpunpack super.raw
```

Mount the image- For eg: system_a

```
mkdir mount_system 
sudo mount -t ext4 -o loop system_a.img mount_system
```